# I want to be able to search 2 websites side-by-side in iframes, using just one search bar. Is my Javascript wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the search console in HTML on a page here:

```
 <title>Search Results</title>
    <style>
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            border: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>


    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <form onsubmit="search(event)">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Enter keywords">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <iframe id="search-results"></iframe>
    <iframe id="search-results"></iframe>
```

My Javascript is:

```
 <script>
        function search(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var keywords = document.getElementById('search-box').value;
            var url1 = 'https://www.vistaprint.fr/search?query=' + keywords;
            var url2 = 'https://www.vistaprint.com/search?query=' + keywords;
            var iframe = document.getElementById('search-results');
            iframe.src = url1 + '&' + url2;
            }
    </script>
```

Ideally, I would like to see two iframes shown side-by-side as search results, but only 'url1' shows in this instance. Am I missing a piece of code?

Ideally, I would like to see two iframes shown side-by-side as search results, but only 'url1' shows in this instance. Am I missing a piece of code?

Comment: You have multiple (logical) errors in your code. You have for both iframes the same id. (id must be unique, otherwise it is no id). `getElementById` gives back 1 element, where src is set. Currently your Url would include `url2` as parameter to `url1` and you would set the attribute only for one iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is like the comment to your question already explained, that you are using 'getElementById' wich gives you 1 element back.

You could add tags to your iframe elements so you can use '[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName?retiredLocale=de)' which will result in an array of 2 elements.

After this you can add the src as you like to your iframe elements like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Search Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <form onsubmit="search(event)">
      <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Enter keywords" />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <iframe id="search-results-fr" name="iframe"></iframe>
    <iframe id="search-results-en" name="iframe"></iframe>
  </body>
  <script>
    function search(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var keywords = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
      var url1 = "https://www.vistaprint.fr/search?query=" + keywords;
      var url2 = "https://www.vistaprint.com/search?query=" + keywords;
      var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
      iframe[0].src = url1;
      iframe[1].src = url2;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is still a duplicated id. While your code may work - it would be good to correct that as well. Like `id="search-results-fr"` & `id="search-results-en"` - from which could follow `document. getElementById("search-results-en").src = url2`

Comment: Thanks Uwe! Of course you could also do it that way.